# jQuery dymanic added input not being deleted

Tags: jquery

I have an event that either deletes or generates an input.

The input is created correctly, however it is never deleted.

I know it must be binded dynamically, however I am not sure how to do it in this case.

```
$(document).on('click', '.ms-optgroup-container', function () {
    var padre = ($(this).parent());

    if ($(padre).hasClass('izq')) {
        if ($(padre).hasClass('callgroup')) {
            $(this).prependTo('#drc_callgroup');

            let inputValue = ($(this).attr('data-extension-name')) ? $(this).attr('data-extension-name') : $(this).text();

            $('#input-option-group').append('<input type="hidden" id="callgroup' + $(this).text() + '" name="callgroup[]" value="' + inputValue + '" />');
        } 
    } else {
        if ($(padre).hasClass('callgroup')) {
            $(this).prependTo('#izq_callgroup');
            $('#callgroup' + $(this).text()).remove();
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: i think your selectors are wrong. `$('.callgroup' + $(this).text()).remove();`the dot is important because you are looking for a class.

Comment: @PhilippSander it's actually an ID. Updated.

Comment: can you check if `$('#callgroup' + $(this).text())` selects an element?

Comment: When you debug, what specifically fails?  What does `'#callgroup' + $(this).text()` resolve to at runtime?  Is it what you expect?  Does that selector find anything?  What do you expect it to find?

Comment: Check your else part ithink it's not trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
id = 'callgroup' + $(this).text();       
document.getElementById(id).outerHTML = "";
```

I just decided to go with vanilla javascript. It just works.

Answer (score 1):

You click on the container. If the container has class "izq" you create the input.

All good.

But when you click the container again, he still have the "izq" class.

Without the html I can't confirm this. But try to remove the "izq" class, after create the input. After that, when you click the container, you will not have the "izq" class, and the else code will be invoked.

If this is not the problem, please describe your problem a little better.